# Is there a standard Kotlin way to make just this one special-case object of a data class have a different toString() method?

Tags: kotlin

Here's my attempt:

```
data class LineStyle(val thickness: Float) {
    override fun toString() =
            if (thickness == 0f) {
                "NO_LINE"
            } else {
                "LineStyle(${thickness}f)"
            }

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val NO_LINE = LineStyle(0f)
    }
}
```

I'd rather override toString separately for the NO_LINE singleton, but don't see how.  I have a lot of classes that have a zero instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different ways you could do this. You could use a `sealed` or `open` class as your actual `LineStyle` and have the `NoLine` as a companion object, forcing you to refer to it as `LineStyle.NoLine`. In that object, you could override the actual `toString()` method with whatever you want. The implementation would look something like this:

```
// sealed so it's easier to deal with in when statements
sealed class LineStyle(val thickness: Float) {

    // defines a no line style
    companion object NoLine: LineStyle(0f) {

        override fun toString() = "NO_LINE"

    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // only able to access it as
    LineStyle.NoLine
}
```

However, with this approach, you lose the `data` aspect of the class. The only other option is to do basically what you have done, instead, maybe use a `when` statement though for future extensibility. It's not the prettiest but it works:

```
data class LineStyle(val thickness: Float) {

    // if you want extensibility, you could use a when statement
    override fun toString() = if(this == NO_LINE) "NO_LINE" else super.toString()

    companion object {
        val NO_LINE = LineStyle(0f)    
    }

}
```

Comment: Hopefully someday: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/data-class-inheritance.md

Comment: @ephemient Yep basically what my answer tries to highlight and skirt around.

Comment: @GlenPeterson it would be safe but only to reference that specific `NO_LINE`. Personally, I wouldn't do this because a `LineStyle(0f)` could be instantiated, and that would be technically equivalent to the `NO_LINE` style but wouldn't evaluate to the same. It's really up to your use case. And the speed boost of using a `===` vs. a `==` would be minimal if anything.